# Is there a way to share authorship of an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, collaboration

In the question [What visual wave behavior help to tell...](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2860/what-visual-wave-behaviour-help-to-tell-if-a-tide-is-going-in-or-out) of the [Earth Science Stack](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/), the current accepted answer was first drafted by me, but another user provided a very good complement to the answer by editing. The point is that, it should be considered a collaborative answer of two users and the other user should be able to get as much credit for the answer as I do. Is there such feature? Can such a feature be added?

Comment: Meh… Why? There's an edit history.

Comment: The other user does not get credit by the editorial activity. When the answer is basically 50% by each user, it would be great to credit the second user as well.

Comment: Community Wiki, if you want.

Comment: Right, but that is not an answer by 2 authors. It is for the entire community and the authors get little credit. If I were to write an essay or a scientific article, there is a clear way of including every author appropriately.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not meant for what you suggest, it's a Q&A site where each question or answer is authored by a single user. In case like you describe, the other user should post new answer, linking to yours, instead of editing your answer. This way he gets full credit and reputation.

Comment: Alternatively, you could accept that the secondary contributor(s) simply do not get internet points for contributing to the answer. If that causes bitterness on their part then they may wish to reflect on what they base their self-image on. Posting a simple mention of the editors in the answer or comment is a good way to give attribution. There are plenty of ways to gain reputation points, and if the other editors are also contributing to the site in other ways, their reputation will ultimately end up reflecting their general contributions as well.

Comment: @JasonC, good point. I like the idea of getting recognition after the fact

Answer (score 3):

You can signal that a post was written by multiple authors by marking it **Community Wiki**, which is a checkbox when editing (or posting in the first place).  You will not gain any further reputation from the post and neither will anybody else, but you'll keep the rep you've already gotten.

The post still counts as yours for badges, and you can't share the rep with somebody else, but Community Wiki signifies that it's a shared effort and you're not taking credit for all of it, which sounds like what you're trying to do.  Further, on CW posts no gravatar shows up, just names, so that further downplays your original contribution.

The edit history will, as always, reveal the details of who did what.

Comment: Indeed, that's the closest thing we got.

Comment: I really think the link to the edit history should be more evident, and we should somehow encourage other users to read through it.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody is going steal your authorship. When a question is edited, a link saying that it was edited appears.

> [image]

Click it. And you will be taken to the world of revisions, where any changes to the post are reflected. Your edit can be seen there too. But editing is needed to *improve* a post, and not to completely change it. If you feel that your opinion changes much, why not post another answer?

The answer posted by another user is another answer, completely. Why do you want to edit it? To get reputation (is this is the reason you need to share authorship)? Or to improve it (if you don't care about rep when editing, all features aimed to show that there is not only one author when question is edited by not-an-author should satisfy you)? Certainly to improve, or it is not? :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there such feature?

I would say that no there is no way to share rep or ownership of a question with another user, but here is a way that they could get some rep for the post:

- Have the other user put the info into a another answer and upvote it there. This would work especially if the user added more info than the stuff they put into your post.

> The point is that, it should be considered a collaborative answer of
>   two users and the other user should be able to get as much credit for
>   the answer as I do.

Technically all questions are collaborative since they can be edited by anyone. And it would get confusing if this happened. You authored the post originally and some users get 2+ from edits and it goes toward their badge progress.

**But if you are truly feeling guilty, then community wiki it like user Monica Cellio suggested.**

Beside those suggestions you can reference their contribution, but all you can do really is mention them.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, let me copy in my suggestion from the [Earth Science meta](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/364/124):

I think a feature request about sharing reputation updates for edited answers and questions is a good idea. A feature description could be:

> **Shared contributions**
>
> Users can provide shares to editors of their posts to award the contributions of other users. Questions are divided in 5 shares, answers in 10 shares. By default all shares belong to the original poster. The original poster is allowed to distribute these shares freely among all editors. Each share is worth one reputation point in future upvotes. So, the editors can gain some reputation points by future upvotes, while the original poster gets fewer points. Downvotes cause reputation loss to all shareholders, without any discrimination about the numbers of shares. Editors need to accept offered shares to become an active shareholder. Additionally, one can earn badges for providing and accepting shares.

Comment: Sounds complicated, though. Mentioned in question comment but I think one important thing is: Even if the "secondary" contributors to such an answer don't get reputation points for that answer, if they generally contribute to the site in other ways, eventually their reputation will more closely reflect their overall contributions. E.g. Say user A provides a good answer, user B contributes, and user C does nothing. Also, in general, users A and B participate in the site, and user C does not. Eventually A and B will have higher rep than C, and the overall goal of rep is still met in the end.

Comment: I.e. relative reputation levels tend to "average out" over a long period of time given a users' relative activity level, so I'm not sure if it's really a problem for one question here and there to not lead to the rep points that a particular user may "deserve". It will even out.